# Reading information from Database collection and then bulk writing OR bulk updating

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am syncing users from another service into our systems. These users are saved into a collection called `TempUser`, that is about 10k documents (This will continue to grow). There is steps that happen whenever I want to update/create a new user and they are as follows:

1. Read the `TempUser` from the database
2. Determine if the document from `TempUser` is an existing user on the database. IF they are an existing user, I would need to update the `User` document in the database. IF they are NOT existing in the database I want to write them as a new `User`. If the user is a new `User`, they require also a document called `Profile`, that is saved as `user.profile` in the `User` document.

Below outlines my code, I believe I can fix this by batching users by 100+, instead of just looping through an array and creating them one by one. I could maybe do a `bulkWrite` or `bulkUpdate`, but I am curious to hear feedback from the community.

Currently, I am reading the users one bye one (haha, I know):

```
      console.log("Creating accounts in system...");
      const PAGE_LIMIT = 1;
      // After user promise resolve, take tempUser and add them as actual users
      const totalUsers = await TempUser.countDocuments();
      let currentUserCount = 0;
      for (let PAGE_NUM = 1; currentUserCount < totalUsers; PAGE_NUM++) {
        const skips = PAGE_LIMIT * (PAGE_NUM - 1);
        const userList = await TempUser.find()
          .skip(skips)
          .limit(PAGE_LIMIT);
        currentUserCount += userList.length;
        const users = await Promise.all(
          userList.map((student) => {
            return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
              // Find school
              const schoolId = await School.findOne(
                {
                  "cleverData.cleverId": student.school,
                },
                { _id: 1 }
              );

              let userObj = {
                firstName: student.name.first,
                lastName: student.name.last,
                cleverId: student.id,
                schoolId: schoolId._id,
                cleverSchoolId: student.school,
                email: student.email,
                studentNumber: student.student_number,
                stemuliDistrictId: student.stemuliDistrictId,
                districtName: student.districtName,
                districtId: student.district,
     
              };

       
              const user = await userSync(studentObj);
              resolve(students);
            });
          })
        );
      }
```

the `userSync` then takes the object and creates or updates the user, depending on if it exists:

```
module.exports = exports = ({
  firstName,
  lastName,
  schoolId,
  cleverSchoolId,
  email,
  studentNumber,
 userPrograms,
  program,
  programsEnrolled,
  term,
  password,
  districtName,
  districtId,
  cleverId,
}) => {
  const avatar =
    "https://stemuli.blob.core.windows.net/stemuli/Placeholders/avatar-placeholder.png";
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    School.findOne({
      _id: schoolId,
    })
      .then(async (schoolDoc) => {
        if (schoolDoc) {
          // We need to get the district name, so get a user with it

          // Check if user exists with email
          let checkedUser = null;
          try {
            let update = {
              $set: {
                "district.cleverId": districtId,
                "district.name": districtName,
                schoolCleverId: cleverSchoolId,
                cleverId: cleverId,
                school: schoolId,
              },
            };
            if (typeof studentPrograms !== "undefined") {
              update = {
                ...update,
                $addToSet: { userPrograms: { $each: userPrograms } },
              };
            }

            checkedUser = await User.findOneAndUpdate({ email: email }, update);
          } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return reject({
              code: 500,
              message: "Unexpected error occured",
            });
          }

          if (checkedUser) {
            return resolve("Email already exists");
          }

          let newUser = null;
          try {
            newUser = await new User({
              name: firstName + " " + lastName,
              email: email.toLowerCase(),
              cleverId: cleverId,
              district: {
                cleverId: districtId,
                name: districtName,
              },
              studentInfo: { sis_id: studentNumber },
              account_type: "student",
              profile_type: "StudentProfile",
              program: program,
              school: schoolId,
              schoolCleverId: cleverSchoolId,
              firstName: firstName,
              lastName: lastName,
              password: password,
            }).save();
            let studentProfile = null;
            try {
              userProfile = await new UserProfile({
                user: newUser._id,
                profile_picture: { url: avatar },
              }).save();

              assignProjects(schoolDoc.district, newUser._id);
              newUser.profile = userProfile._id;
              newUser
                .save()
                .then((userDocFinal) => {
                  payload = {
                    id: userDocFinal.id,
                    firstName: userDocFinal.firstName,
                    lastName: userDocFinal.lastName,
                    name: userDocFinal.name,
                    profile_picture: {
                      url: avatar,
                    },
                    hasDailyReport: false,
                    hasSignedOn: false,

                    account_type: userDocFinal.account_type,
                    hasAssessment: userDocFinal.hasAssessment,
                  };

                  resolve(payload);
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                  console.error(err);
                  reject({
                    code: 500,
                    message: "Error saving profile ID to new User profile id",
                  });
                });
            } catch (err) {
              console.error(err);
              reject({
                code: 500,
                message: "Error saving Student Profile",
              });
            }
          } catch (err) {
            console.error("Issue creating user profile");
          }

   
        } else {
          console.log("Could not located school with id");
        }
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        reject({
          code: 400,
          message: "School is not registered with system",
        });
      });
  });
};
```

Comment: Are you creating one user or 100 at a time?

Comment: I am reading an array 100 at a time and looping through that to create each user

Answer (score 1):

You can use `upsert=true` to insert the document if it's not already inserted. You can refer to this link : [MongoDB-FindOneAndUpdate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/)

And for minimising the time of processing the different documents and collections, you should use indexes. For example, `schoolId` should be an index.

Also, you can refer to this article about cursor based pagination: [Cursor-Based-Pagination](https://www.codementor.io/@arpitbhayani/fast-and-efficient-pagination-in-mongodb-9095flbqr)

TLDR; Cursor based pagination uses the fact that document id's are in an incremental order, so you can iterate through data using them (and they've proven to be more performant than Skip-Limit approach).